# It would be nice to exclude areas when searching for jobs

Tags: feature-request, jobs, search

Would it be possible to filter out certain areas from a job search? At least by city, state/prov name?

Example (especially since NYC seems to be well represented in Careers):

I've spent significant time in NYC, and it's a great city, but not a city I'd ever want to live in or around. I realize I might need to exclude New York, Brooklyn, Stamford, etc. Less than perfect, but helpful.

Searching the U.S. and filtering out major areas (like NY, SF) would give a pretty good idea of "other" options around the country. This is helpful if my goal is a change of scenery, but to somewhere other than a big city.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of that, what about a heat map of available jobs around the world?

Comment: I like stv's suggestion, but am unfamiliar with a heat map. NickLarsen - Could you provide some more info on that?